# How to use a controlled RadioGroup in react when mapping over an array of values to populate the radio buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a predefined set of arrays to populate several RadioGroups. The components hierarchy is defined in the codesandbox to mimic the one in my project.

Every time I hit the radio button it says to use a controlled radiogroup. According to MaterialUI, it says to add value and `onChange` to the Radiogroup instead of the individual Radio component. The problem is, the value is looped over the array and dynamically assigned. What am I doing wrong?

[**codesandbox here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-rgb-v6elsy?file=/src/MainComponent.js)

```
  <FormControl>
    <RadioGroup name="row-radio-buttons-group" defaultValue={defaultValue}>
      <FormLabel> {radiolabel} </FormLabel>
      {radiodata.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item} style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Radio
                  size="small"
                  value={item}
                  name={item}
                  checked={radiovalues[item]}
                  onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                />
              }
              label={item}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is basically removing the handler from the Radios in your codesandbox and just moving it to RadioGroup instead.

Rather than passing the value to the Radio directly, RadioGroup does that for you. See this [updated code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-violet-4lcwy1) (the only file I updated is CustomRadioGroup.js).

Answer (score 0):

For the Radio `name` attribute, you should use the same name for each Radio component in the RadioGroup.

For the Radio `checked` attribute, it should be a boolean, something like `values.itemId == item.itemId` to compare the selected value to the value for that Radio button.

You can replace the onChange with onClick event handler, to update the selected value to the clicked value. `onClick = (() => {setFieldValue('itemId', item.itemId)})`.